# Cannot connect from external PC to Java application running in Docker container - Linux

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, docker, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Java server application running in Docker Container. The container runs in a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), with a static IP address. Another Java application, running in a PC, has to connect to the Java server application.

The server app listens for TCP connection requests and the PC App can open a TCP connection, knowing port and static IP address of Server App.

Let me say that the app server listens on port 5000 for TCP connection requests; then, when a TCP connection arrives from external, the TCP server releases a connection assigning a port in the range 5000-20000. So first question is if this range 5000-20000 to be exposed?

Before, the Java server application runned in a linux server, without container, and it worked.

Now, with the Server App inside the Docker container, the connection is refused; I guess that there is a problem of ports.

The Java application is configured by a dockerfile like that:

```
FROM openjdk:8-oraclelinux8
WORKDIR /mydir
# VOLUME . /
COPY ["./My_name_Java_app.jar", "./My_name_Java_app.properties", "./"]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5000-20000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/java", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-jar", "My_name_Java_app.jar"]
```

I have read that I have to publish the ports on Docker run command, but when I run the container by:

```
docker run -d --name my_container -p 5000-20000:5000-20000/tcp -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -v /root/my_app/volume:/mydir my_image
```

I get the following error (in Linux terminal - note that the final full stop is exactly whay I get):

```
linux docker: Error response from daemon xxxxxxxxx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint Error starting userland proxy:.
```

So finally my target is that the PC app can connect to Server app using the port 5000 and opening a connection in the range of port (5001-20000).

I also exposed ports 80 and 8080 because the Server App must perform some http requests to a website, so I suppose that I have to expose the ports 80 and 8080; other question is if do I have also to expose and publish 80 and 8080 by -p option?

By the way, if I delete (see below) the -p option with 80 and 8080, I get always the same error.

```
docker run -d --name my_container -p 5000-20000:5000-20000/tcp -v /root/my_app/volume:/mydir my_image
```

Moreover, if I eliminate at all the -p option, the container starts without errors.

Comment: What port is your java server listening on? Why does your dockerfile suggest to expose ports `1000-2000` and yet you're forwarding from `10110-21200` on the host to `10110-21200` on the container?

Comment: That’s a lot of ports. Are you sure you need to expose all of them? // You don’t need any exposed ports for outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: AT the end of the story nothing was really wrong, simply I had to expose (inside the dockerfile) and publish with -p option (in docker run command) only the only port that I really need (that is the 5000), and not the big range of ports I considered at beginning.